# REAL_GET_TASKS permission removed?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, deprecated

After deprecating in Android 5.1.1 GET_TASKS permission for getting info about all running processes on device was added a new one: REAL_GET_TASKS which obligates app to be system or have manufacturer signature. But currently [developers page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) doesn't contain any info about REAL_GET_TASKS and Manifest class hasn't such field. Was it removed? If yes, are there still ways to gather information about processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That permission is not part of the Android SDK, but [it still exists in the manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml). But, as you note, it is a `signature|privileged` permission, not one that ordinary Android SDK apps can hold.

Comment: Got it. If my application was moved to /system/priv-app it still hasn't signature permission. And vice versa signed application could not be system to get those rights. Is it correct?

Comment: @SerhiiPetrenko: Correct. AFAIK, you would have rights to request `privileged` permissions, but that's not something I have worked with.